# Compare two HashMap and multiply map values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have two HashMap and lets say they having the following values:

```
 HashMap1 : <x, 1>, <y, 2>, <z, 3>

 HashMap2 : <x,10>, <y, 20>, <z,30>
```

I want to multiply corresponding values then sum these values like: 1*10 + 2*20 + 3*30. However, I am not sure if I have to use 2 loops or some other iteration. I use one loop but it did no solved the problem:

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    int sum=0;
    if(map2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
        sum+=entry.getValue() * ...; //it gets map1 values but I also need map2 values to multiply
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `sum += entry.getValue() * map2.get(entry.getKey()) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `Java 8`:

```
int sum = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    sum += entry.getValue() * map2.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 1);
}
```

Since `Java 8`:

```
int sum = map1.entrySet().stream()
   .mapToInt(e -> e.getValue() * map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 1)).sum();
```

Note:
You need to also handle keys which are different between two maps. I assumed that these two maps contains exactly the same keys. Just to keep it simple and clear.

Comment: Multiplying by `0` will ruin the result

Comment: In method 2, using 0 or 1 in `(e.getKey(), 0)` does not change the result while in method 1 it changes. Is there any mistake?

Comment: @hexadecimal, in both cases default value used in `map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), defaultValue)` should give the same result for `0` or `1`. For example, assume `HashMap2` does not contain key `y`. In this case, with default value set to `0` sum is `100` (1 * 10 + 2 * 0 + 3 * 30) and for `1` sum is `102` (1 * 10 + 2 * 1 + 3 * 30).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand completely.